# Zip creation using CMake with no relative path

Tags: cmake

I want to bundle the build artifacts into a zip to deliver them on the delivery server. That for I integrated the zip creation into the CMake routine.

```
# zip the final release files into the build artifact
# call the zipping with 'cmake --build . --target zip' or 'make zip'
string(TIMESTAMP DATE_STRING %Y%m%d)
add_custom_target(zip
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar "cfv" "${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}-${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}-${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION}-${DATE_STRING}.zip" "--format=zip"  "--"
            "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/release/*")
```

The artifacts are bundeld into the `bin/release` folder in the ProjectSourceDir.
My problem is, that the zip file has the relative path to the files from my build directory. So all files are located under `../bin/release/` which is not what I want. I want to have the files in the "home folder" of the zip file.

I've found the solution to prepare the zip folder in my build folder, but thats something I think is very unpractical or looks dirty to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `WORKING_DIRECTORY` can be specified to the `add_custom command`.

```
add_custom_target(zip 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar cvf ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}-${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}-${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION}-${DATE_STRING}.zip --format=zip .
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/release
)
```

You don't need all that extra quoting as given in the example.

Comment: This works perfect. The only adjustment I had to do was to add an ```../``` before the zip file name, otherwise the zip is created in the working dir, which can resolute (with no propper clean up before zip creation) in an old zip in the newly created one.
Thank You very much